# sql newbie: multi variable grouping and aggregation

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate

the raw data looks like this
[image]

I want to transform this so I could know for each country_code, how many people register with facebook, and how many register with email.

like:

```
country_code|facebook|email
---------------------------
AE          |  4     | 5
AL          |  11    | 10
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum` with `case` and `group by`:

```
select country_code,
    sum(case when register_with = 'facebook' then 1 else 0 end) facebook,
    sum(case when register_with = 'email' then 1 else 0 end) email
from yourtable 
group by country_code
```

Comment: thank you so much. this solve my problem. I will looking into `case`'s documentation!